# Defining first axis break point for datetime using R's ggplot2

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, axis-labels, posixct

I have time series data for a 12 hour period starting at 01:30:00 (01:30 AM).

I'd like major breaks of 2 hours and minor breaks of 1 hour.

I use ggplot2, and scale_x_datetime to set the breaks and date_minor_breaks

I'm getting these major breaks by default: 03AM, 05AM, 07AM, 09AM, 11AM.
I'd prefer these major breaks: 2AM, 4AM, 6AM, 8AM, 10AM

It appears a vector of breaks can be manually set, though I'm not sure how to do this for a datetime data type.
I would also have thought I could override the default by specifying a first major tick mark (first break), then "breaks" could fill out the rest.
I'd prefer to avoid hard-coding a vector of breaks, seeing as this code needs to be reusable (for datasets with varying start times).

```
#quick sample data set
DF_test <- data.frame(matrix("NA", ncol = 2, nrow = 6))
DF_test$TS <- as.POSIXct(
            c("2017/01/01 01:30:00", 
            "2017/01/01 03:40:00", 
            "2017/01/01 05:10:00", 
            "2017/01/01 07:05:00", 
            "2017/01/01 09:25:00", 
            "2017/01/01 11:00:00"
            ),
            tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01",usetz=F)
DF_test$value <- c(50,51,45,50,57,49)

#Create plot
ggplot(DF_test) +
    scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),
                     date_minor_breaks = "1 hour",
                     labels = date_format("%I\n%p")) +
    geom_line(aes(TS, value))
```

Plot of sample data:

[image]

If you're interested - end goal:

Plot with 4 hour major breaks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `seq.POSIXt()` from the smallest to the largest `POSIXct` to generate the x axis labels  using `by = "2 hour"`. Then you round it up to the next hour using `lubridate::ceiling_date`. Is this the desired output?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)
ggplot(DF_test) +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq.POSIXt( ceiling_date(min(DF_test$TS), unit = "hour"),
                                      ceiling_date(max(DF_test$TS), unit = "hour"), by = "2 hour" ),
                                      labels = date_format("%H:%M %p") ) +
geom_line (aes(TS, value))
```

[image]

In relation to your end goal, just replace in the `by` argument `"2 hour"` by `"4 hour"`